# How to print code on HTML

Tags: html

I want to display code characters on an HTML page. But no matter what I try it always renders HTML characters. `pre` or `code` doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: "code characters"? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `<xmp>` tag doesn't require the contents to be escaped.

eg:

```
<xmp>
    <p>Blah &nbsp;</p>
</xmp>
```

...will look like this on your screen:

```
    <p>Blah &nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: +1 It's deprecated, but it's so easy to use.. Expecially for test/debug purposes it's the best way, I think. Hope it will be valid again!!

Comment: Better to use the solution suggested by weeger below, i.e. to use PHP htmlentities().

Answer (score 9):

You need to use [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#entities) instead of the plain characters themselves:

```
<code>&lt;HTML&gt;</code>
```

The elements `code` and `pre` are just to mark the content as *code* or *preformated*.

Answer (score 3):

By escaping them.
`&amp;` will print `&`
`&lt;` will print `>`

You didn't mention what you're using to generate the html, if you're manually editing, some editors have options to escape a selection. If you're using a language, look for some function that escapes html special characters. (google for how to escape html in `language-name-here`)

Answer (score 3):

Since  tag is now depreciated : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

You can use PHP to convert HTML tags :

`<code>
   <?php print htmlentities('<p>Blah</p>'); ?>
</code>`

Answer (score 2):

Look for an HTML encode function in your language.

```
string s = HtmlEncode(myInput);
response.write(s)
```

or similar

Answer (score 0):

To display HTML tags within a browser, you can surround the output with
`<xmp><p>HTML<p></xmp>` tags

*This is the easy way to fix this problem. but this tag already deprecated.*

for more details : [xmp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)

You can use `htmlentities`.But you can't use this inside the JavaScript file. because JavaScript runs in the user's browser. PHP runs on the server.

```
<code>
    <?php print htmlentities('<p>HTML</p>');?>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am displaying vue code in html content block with this.
wrap the the code I want o display twice.
for example:

```
<pre>
<xmp>  
<template> <h1>{{ title }}</h1></template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      title: 'My First Vue app :) '
     }
    }
 }
</script>
<xmp>
</pre>
```

The example [here](https://infomasud.com/vue-template-refs/)

Answer (score -2):

Download tinymce From

https://www.tinymce.com/download/

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src='tinymce/js/tinymce.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#myTextarea',
        height: 300,
        width:800,
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
          'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
          'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <textarea  name="myTextarea" id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="50">Hello Ashish</textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='save'/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
try wrapping HTML content in <textarea></textarea> For ex: <pre> <textarea> <html> </html> </textarea> </pre> Works in awesome way. You don't have to use obsolete <XMP> example tag. <textarea> tag will wrap the content in text area. Try out !
```