# have <p> display on page and not in code

Tags: html, tags

I am trying to write `It looks this way because the HTML tag <p> is does not skip lines without a break, <br> tag.` on my html page but it always cuts off the tags. How can I leave them on the page?

Comment: Possible similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756164/how-to-print-code-on-html

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

like this : `&lt;p&gt;`i am in a p tag`&lt;/p&gt;`

result is: <p>i am in a p tag</p>