# Integrating a stemmer with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, stemming

I want to implement KrovetzStemmer for the pages that I download. The biggest problem that I have is I cannot simply use the `body().text()` with the given document and then stem all the words. The reason is because I need `href` links which should not be stemmed at all. So I thought maybe if I could get the body with `href` links then I could split it by href and then use a `LinkedHashMap` as `Element` and Boolean or an enum type which would specify whether the `Element` is text or link.

So the problem is let's say given HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> This is the heading part. This is for testing purposes only.</h1>
<a href="http://www.firstsite.com/this is a sub directory/">First Link</a>
<p>This is the first paragraph to be considered.</p>
<a href="http://www.secondsite.com/it is the correct page/">Second Link</a>
<p>This is the second paragraph to be considered.</p>
<img border="0" src="/images/pulpit.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228">
<a href="http://www.thirdsite.com">Third Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to only get this:

```
This is the heading part. This is for testing purposes only.
<a href="http://www.firstsite.com/this is a sub directory/">First Link</a>
This is the first paragraph to be considered.
<a href="http://www.secondsite.com/it is the correct page/">Second Link</a>
This is the second paragraph to be considered.
<a href="http://www.thirdsite.com">Third Link</a>
```

And then split them and then insert into a `LinkedHashMap` so if I do something like this:

```
int i = 1;
for (Entry<Element, Boolean> entry : splitedList.getEntry()) {
      if(!entry.getValue()) { System.out.println(i + ": " + entry.getKey());}
      i++;    
}
```

Then it would print:

```
1: This is the heading part. This is for testing purposes only.
3: This is the first paragraph to be considered.
5: This is the second paragraph to be considered.
```

So that I can apply stemming and keep the order of iteration.

Now, I have no idea how to implement this as I don't know how to:

a) Get the body text with `href` links only

b) Split the body(I know with Strings we can always use `split()` but I am talking about the Elements of body of a page)

How would I be able to do these two things above?

Also I am not too sure whether my solution is a good solution or not. Are there better/easier ways to do that?

Comment: For better help try adding example of input and expected output/result with little explanation why is it expected.

Comment: @Pshemo I gave the example now.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand your requirement, I am updating the post with new answer here:

so considering you have the html Document `doc` by parsing the given HTML

you can get all the `a` tags and wrap them in `<xmp>` tags (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756215/2549021))

```
for (Element element : doc.body().select("a"))
     element.wrap("<xmp></xmp>");
```

Now you need to load the new HTML into `doc`, so Jsoup would avoid parsing the content inside `<xmp>` tags

```
 doc = Jsoup.parse(doc.html());
 System.out.println(doc.body().text());
```

The output would be:

```
This is the heading part. This is for testing purposes only.
<a href="http://www.firstsite.com/this is a sub directory/">First Link</a>
This is the first paragraph to be considered.
<a href="http://www.secondsite.com/it is the correct page/">Second Link</a>
This is the second paragraph to be considered.
<a href="http://www.thirdsite.com">Third Link</a>
```

Now you can go ahead and do what you want with the output.

---

**Updating the code based on the comment for splitting**

```
for (Element element : doc.body().select("a"))
    element.wrap("<xmp>split-me-here</xmp>split-me-here");  

doc = Jsoup.parse(doc.html());
        
int cnt = 0;
List<String> splitText = Arrays.asList(doc.body().text().split("split-me-here"));
for (String text : splitText) {
    cnt++;
    if (!text.contains("</a>"))
        System.out.println(cnt + "." + text.trim());
}
```

The above code will print following output:

> 1.This is the heading part. This is for testing purposes only.
>
> 3.This is the first paragraph to be considered.
>
> 5.This is the second paragraph to be considered.

Comment: I don't think you understood it right.
I don't want to remove anything from the elements. As I mentioned I can simply stem all the words by just getting `.body().text()` which already returns scrapped text.

Comment: So do you need the body text or the elements text?

Comment: I need the text and `href` elements that are in the body of the document.

Comment: To get the `href` elements you can always use `doc.body().select("a")`

Comment: Yes but you are telling me to get them separately. I need the text and href elements together, in order.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know if there is a way to split them based on the wrap? For instance, can I check if it is wrapped with <xmp> or any other way?

Comment: @SarpKaya I have added the code for splitting too. I hope this would solve your query.

Comment: it did not work, at first step I am getting results like `<a id="top"></a>` which is not a 'href'. So I changed it to `a[href]` which made the first step working but then splitting part doesn't work.

Comment: I solved the issue above. My last problem is, I don't want to iterate them as Strings after splitting, is it possible to split them and iterate by their elements?