# Show code in a P tag without loading it

Tags: html, css

I have a simple style like this,

```
.codecontain{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and I would like to display a code in it like this,

```
<div class="codecontain">
<p><hr></p>
</div>
```

but when I do it HTML displays the result but I want HTML to show text.
I know there are syntax highlighters but I don't want to use them.

Comment: Use `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for >. The `&xx;` syntax is used for [HTML encoded strings](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

Comment: I assume you are talking about sth like that: https://jsfiddle.net/bj39p03x/

Comment: you have to escape brackets, else html will be interpreted. Css has never been able to do such a thing, there were tags long ago but also long ago not working .... some history and what to do about those tags you SHOULD NOT USE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to André's answer, here's a codepen, his answer is correct.

```
<div class="codecontain">
<p>&lt;hr&gt;</p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGwKqe

Another approach would be using

```
<xmp></xmp>
```

as suggested here [How to print code on HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756164/how-to-print-code-on-html)

Be careful as xmp is deprecated.

also, possible duplicate

Comment: Ok, thanks! Sorry If This Is A Duplicate I Maybe Worded It Wrong In The Search.

Comment: @PrabhSingh watch out for xmp ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp , could be a bad idea to use

Comment: Totally agree, it's deprecated, as stated in the link. Just put it there for informational purposes, editing original post to point out that xmp is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the < with `&lt;` and the > with `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do it manually you could use some javascript to convert it.

I wrapped the html in comments (*and removed the comments in js*) for two reasons. One is to avoid having the html rendered normally and then overwritten, and the seconds so that you can have invalid html as you did. (*the `hr` element is not valid inside a `p` so the browser would correct it and the script would show the corrected html*)

```js
var code = document.querySelectorAll('.codecontain');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(code, function(node) {
  node.textContent = node.innerHTML.slice(4,-3);
});
```

```css
.codecontain {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="codecontain"><!--
<p><hr></p>
--></div>
```