# Tool or library to format any code to be displayed in HTML

Tags: formatting

As the title says. I need some tool, library or workaround which can take a code file i.e., JS, Python, C# etc and make that code displayable in HTML page.

Kind of like what GitHub do when someone tries to open a code in project.

It would be nice if there is some Python implementation for this. But others like nodejs, php, or plain js will do as well.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Since, it's not allowed to get recommendation regarding libraries, I will add what I have attempted. So far I have been thinking only vital part while displaying the code will be to retain white spaces. So probably replace these with `&nbsp;` probably. But I'm sure there are better solutions out there. And that's exactly what I am here for.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Did you try showing the code using the tag <pre>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756164/how-to-print-code-on-html